# Python Convert String List to List

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, type-conversion

So I have a list of python formatted like:

```
x = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6,]', ...]
```

Is there a way to convert the "inner lists" to actual lists? So the output would be

```
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], ....]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example with `json`:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6]']
>>> [json.loads(y) for y in x]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Please limit your strings to `dict`s and `list`s only.

Comment: I accepted this answer versus the one proposed by khelwood (his solution did also solve my problem) because my full code already uses the json library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for this kind of conversion. You can use `map` to apply the conversion to each element of your list.

```
from ast import literal_eval

x = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6,]']
x = map(literal_eval, x)
print x
```

gives

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is great and it converts many types, but it'll give error if the list has any tags (i.e. `<tag>` etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval to evaluate strings as code.

```
x = ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6,]']
y = [eval(s) for s in x]
```

Comment: Use of `eval` is generally discouraged.